# Apache 2.4 httpd in Docker doesn't start when loading proxy module

Tags: php, apache, docker, mod-proxy

I'm building a Apache2.4 stack with Docker. During configuration, the server doesn't start:

```
apache-php-fpm-docker_apache_1 exited with code 1
```

Found out this happens after adding the following line to load a module:

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
```

I think that I did something wrong, but how can I get the error message to see what's the problem?

### What I already tried

Running `httpd -h`I saw the following option:

`-e level           : show startup errors of level (see LogLevel)`

So I tried `ENTRYPOINT httpd -k start -e debug` and see now some logs, but not errors. And the webserver doesn't start, not even when the errors were fixed.

### Full apache config

```
Listen 80
ServerRoot "/usr/local/apache2"
DocumentRoot "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs"
ServerName localhost
LogLevel warn

LoadModule mpm_event_module modules/mod_mpm_event.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule access_compat_module modules/mod_access_compat.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule reqtimeout_module modules/mod_reqtimeout.so
LoadModule filter_module modules/mod_filter.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule version_module modules/mod_version.so
LoadModule unixd_module modules/mod_unixd.so
LoadModule status_module modules/mod_status.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so

#LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
#LoadModule proxy_fcgi_module modules/mod_proxy_fcgi.so

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
</IfModule>

<Directory />
    AllowOverride none
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

#ProxyPassMatch ^/(.*\.php(/.*)?)$ fcgi://php:9000/usr/local/apache2/htdocs/$1
<Directory "/usr/local/apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymlinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

### Docker Compose

```
version: "2.4"
services: 
  apache:
    image: httpd:2.4
    volumes:
      - ./apache/httpd.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf
      - ./src:/usr/local/apache2/htdocs
    ports:
      - 80:80

  php:
    image: php:7.3-fpm
    volumes_from:
      - apache
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, add `ErrorLog /proc/self/fd/2` to your `http.conf` to enable the error log.

Then, I saw the error log of your situation:

```
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/aa$ docker run -idt -v ${PWD}/httpd.conf:/usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf -p 9000:80 httpd:2.4
fd0d0b45bd8e25e5ce8219d6b96e5b446307d7a76bf7e3eecb47e23d93b04368
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/aa$ docker ps -a
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND              CREATED             STATUS                    PORTS               NAMES
fd0d0b45bd8e        httpd:2.4           "httpd-foreground"   3 seconds ago       Exited (1) 1 second ago                       agitated_edison
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/aa$ docker logs agitated_edison
[Wed Jun 19 08:45:20.774433 2019] [core:emerg] [pid 1:tid 139720185319488] (22)Invalid argument: AH00024: Couldn't set permissions on the proxy mutex; check User and Group directives
[Wed Jun 19 08:45:20.774495 2019] [proxy:crit] [pid 1:tid 139720185319488] (22)Invalid argument: AH02478: failed to create proxy mutex
AH00016: Configuration Failed
```

From the error log: it seems failure when create proxy mutex for `proxy_module`. So, I add next to `httpd.conf`, then everything works:

```
<IfModule unixd_module>
User daemon
Group daemon
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Piping to `/proc/self/fd/2` solved the logging problem, thanks! I doesn't recognized this because by the executable name `httpd-foreground`I assumed that it would already print every logs to stdout/stderr.